# facebook scraping issue when using another URL for metadata

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am implementing FB share in my website. Metadata for it is at different url from the content. So i wrote

```
<link rel="opengraph" href="{metaDataUrl}"/>
```

in the main content page

MetadataURL i wrote

```
<head>
    <link rel="origin" href="{source_url}"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="Article" />
    <meta property="og:title" content='<%=title%>' />
    <meta property="og:description" content='<%=details%>' />
    <meta property="og:image" content="./cover.jpg" />
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
```

But when i used the https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
for checking.

it shows warning

Inferred Property
The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Inferred Property
The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

but  Open Graph properties are right.but shared data is different.
below is snap

[FB issue image]http://hardikravindraraut.in/images/fbissue.PNG

Comment: Can you add a url that this is happening on so that I can try reproduce? The one in your screenshot is giving a 404

Answer (score 0):

It Happened that MetadataURL can contain advance data. But basic Property like title and description should be provided main page. I found this detail in Facebook FAQs.